# Cannot solve spring security

Tags: spring, mongodb, elasticsearch, grails

I want to make a simple search using grails, elasticsearch and mongodb. But i cannot solve the following problem. 
Version: grails- 3.3.2
elasticsearch - 5.4.1

Here is my build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        grailsVersion = '3.3.2'
        gormVersion = '6.1.8.RELEASE'
        elasticsearchVersion = '5.4.1'
        elasticsearchAttachmentsVersion = '5.4.1'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.energizedwork.webdriver-binaries:webdriver-binaries-gradle-plugin:1.1"
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.energizedwork:idea-gradle-plugins:1.4"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:${gormVersion-".RELEASE"}"
        classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.14.6"
    }
}

version "0.1"
group "hellokitty"

apply plugin:"eclipse"
apply plugin:"idea"
apply plugin:"war"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin:"com.energizedwork.webdriver-binaries"
apply plugin:"com.energizedwork.idea-project-components"
apply plugin:"asset-pipeline"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-gsp"

ext {
    gradleWrapperVersion = '3.5'
}


repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.grails:grails-bom:$grailsVersion"
    }
    applyMavenExclusions false
}  
dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.grails:grails-core"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    compile "org.grails:grails-logging"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-rest"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-i18n"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-services"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-interceptors"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:async"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:events"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:gsp"
    //compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"
//    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.5.Final"

    compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.2.0'
    compile "org.grails.plugins:mongodb"
    compile("org.grails:gorm-mongodb-spring-boot:6.1.2.RELEASE")
    compile "org.grails.plugins:elasticsearch:2.4.0"
    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    profile "org.grails.profiles:web"
    runtime 'org.elasticsearch.plugin:mapper-attachments:2.4.6'
    runtime "org.glassfish.web:el-impl:2.1.2-b03"
    //runtime "com.h2database:h2"
    runtime "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc"
    runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:2.14.6"

    testCompile "org.grails:grails-gorm-testing-support"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-web-testing-support"
    testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:3.6.0"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:3.6.0"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:3.6.0"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-api:3.6.0"
}

bootRun {
    //jvmArgs = ['-Des.path.home=/farhad/Downloads/elasticsearch-5.4.1']
    jvmArgs('-Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always')
    addResources = true
}


webdriverBinaries {
    chromedriver '2.32'
    geckodriver '0.18.0'
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    systemProperty "geb.env", System.getProperty('geb.env')
    systemProperty "webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty('webdriver.chrome.driver')
    systemProperty "webdriver.gecko.driver", System.getProperty('webdriver.gecko.driver')
}

assets {
    minifyJs = true
    minifyCss = true
}
```

Here is my application.yml file

---

```
grails:
    profile: web
    codegen:
        defaultPackage: hellokitty
    spring:
        transactionManagement:
            proxies: false
    gorm:
        reactor:
            # Whether to translate GORM events into Reactor events
            # Disabled by default for performance reasons
            events: false
info:
    app:
        name: '@info.app.name@'
        version: '@info.app.version@'
        grailsVersion: '@info.app.grailsVersion@'
spring:
    main:
        banner-mode: "off"
    groovy:
        template:
            check-template-location: false

# Spring Actuator Endpoints are Disabled by Default
endpoints:
    enabled: false
    jmx:
        enabled: true

---
grails:
    mime:
        disable:
            accept:
                header:
                    userAgents:
                        - Gecko
                        - WebKit
                        - Presto
                        - Trident
        types:
            all: '*/*'
            atom: application/atom+xml
            css: text/css
            csv: text/csv
            form: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
            html:
              - text/html
              - application/xhtml+xml
            js: text/javascript
            json:
              - application/json
              - text/json
            multipartForm: multipart/form-data
            pdf: application/pdf
            rss: application/rss+xml
            text: text/plain
            hal:
              - application/hal+json
              - application/hal+xml
            xml:
              - text/xml
              - application/xml
    urlmapping:
        cache:
            maxsize: 1000
    controllers:
        defaultScope: singleton
    converters:
        encoding: UTF-8
    views:
        default:
            codec: html
        gsp:
            encoding: UTF-8
            htmlcodec: xml
            codecs:
                expression: html
                scriptlets: html
                taglib: none
                staticparts: none
endpoints:
    jmx:
        unique-names: true

---
elasticSearch:
    client:
        mode: local
    client.hosts:
        - {host: localhost, port: 9300}
    disableAutoIndex: false
    datastoreImpl: mongoDatastore
    bulkIndexOnStartup: true
    index:
        store.type: mmapfs

environments:
    development:
        grails:
            serverURL: http://localhost:8080
            dataSource:
            mongodb:
                host: "localhost"
                port: 27017
                username: ""
                password: ""
                databaseName: "people"
            elasticSearch:
                client:
                    mode: local
                    transport.sniff: true
                bulkIndexOnStartup: true
                datastoreImpl: mongoDatastore
    production:
        grails:
            mongodb:
                host: "localhost"
                port: 27017
                username: ""
                password: ""
                databaseName: "people"
            elasticSearch:
                client:
                  mode: node
```

Here is the error i got

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java - run-app
| Resolving Dependencies. Please wait...

CONFIGURE SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1.633 secs
| Running application...
objc[75839]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x100de24c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x100eaa4e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
2018-02-11 20:27:55.601 ERROR --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Destroy method on bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory' threw an exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@127e70c5: startup date [Sun Feb 11 20:27:53 BDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:414)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationListenerDetector.postProcessBeforeDestruction(ApplicationListenerDetector.java:97)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:253)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:523)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.destroySingletons(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:968)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1030)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:556)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:83)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:387)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:374)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at hellokitty.Application.main(Application.groovy:9)

2018-02-11 20:27:55.620 ERROR --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplicationPostProcessor' defined in hellokitty.Application: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor]: Factory method 'grailsApplicationPostProcessor' threw exception; nested exception is org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: Error instantiated artefact class [class grails.plugins.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchService] of type [class org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsServiceClass]: InvocationTargetException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:115)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:83)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:387)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:374)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at hellokitty.Application.main(Application.groovy:9)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor]: Factory method 'grailsApplicationPostProcessor' threw exception; nested exception is org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: Error instantiated artefact class [class grails.plugins.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchService] of type [class org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsServiceClass]: InvocationTargetException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
        ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: Error instantiated artefact class [class grails.plugins.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchService] of type [class org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsServiceClass]: InvocationTargetException
        at grails.core.ArtefactHandlerAdapter.newArtefactClass(ArtefactHandlerAdapter.java:170)
        at grails.core.DefaultGrailsApplication.addArtefact(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:825)
        at grails.core.DefaultGrailsApplication.addOverridableArtefact(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:815)
        at grails.core.DefaultGrailsApplication.addOverridableArtefact(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:800)
        at org.grails.plugins.AbstractGrailsPluginManager.registerProvidedArtefacts(AbstractGrailsPluginManager.java:310)
        at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.performGrailsInitializationSequence(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:110)
        at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.initializeGrailsApplication(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:94)
        at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.setApplicationContext(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:225)
        at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.<init>(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:78)
        at grails.boot.config.GrailsAutoConfiguration.grailsApplicationPostProcessor(GrailsAutoConfiguration.groovy:68)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1427)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
        ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrConstructorNewInstance(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1076)
        at grails.core.ArtefactHandlerAdapter.newArtefactClass(ArtefactHandlerAdapter.java:161)
        ... 39 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/elasticsearch/common/xcontent/NamedXContentRegistry;
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlClassGetDeclaredFields(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1797)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$1$1.run(CachedClass.java:54)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$1$1.run(CachedClass.java:52)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$1.initValue(CachedClass.java:52)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$1.initValue(CachedClass.java:49)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.getLocked(LazyReference.java:49)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.get(LazyReference.java:36)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass.getFields(CachedClass.java:278)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.addFields(MetaClassImpl.java:2380)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.inheritFields(MetaClassImpl.java:2375)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setupProperties(MetaClassImpl.java:2262)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.addProperties(MetaClassImpl.java:3323)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.initialize(MetaClassImpl.java:3288)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClassUnderLock(ClassInfo.java:260)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClass(ClassInfo.java:302)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.getMetaClass(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:261)
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.reflect.ClassPropertyFetcher.getStaticPropertyValue(ClassPropertyFetcher.java:176)
        at org.grails.core.AbstractGrailsClass.getStaticPropertyValue(AbstractGrailsClass.java:239)
        at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsServiceClass.<init>(DefaultGrailsServiceClass.java:34)
        ... 45 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.NamedXContentRegistry
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 68 common frames omitted


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
> Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
| Error Failed to start server (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Would anybody give me any suggestion how I can solve this problem ??

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you it's missing a class:

```
org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.NamedXContentRegistry
```

Please check if this issue helps resolving the problem:

```
https://github.com/noamt/elasticsearch-grails-plugin/issues/198
```